# Spring Boot Static Resources

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Spring Boot with Mvc and AngularJs. I modified the View Resolver of my app so I can point my application to look on the "WEB-INF/pages/" folder for my static html files. Now on the html file I declared the source of my AngularJs libraries by using the webjars dependency

```
<script src="webjars/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I know that in order to make this work is I have to declare the classpath of the webjars libray on the application's ResourceHandlerRegistry so on my configuration file I added only this line of code

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

After adding this line my code somehow works but what makes me curious is that about this line on my html file

```
<script src="resources/js/angular/app.js"></script>
```

I noticed that on a Spring MVC application that in order for Spring to detect the Javascript files under the webapp's resource folder is that we have to declare that folder on the `ResourceHandlerRegistry` just like this

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

but I haven't declared my webapp's resource folder on my Spring Boot's `ResourceHandlerRegistry`but still the application can see my app.js file and my AngularJs codes still works. Here is the file structure of my Application

`src
|--main
     |--java
     |--resources
     |--webapp
          |--resources
               |--js
                   |--angular
                        |--app.js
          |--WEB-INF
               |--index.html`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's how spring boot Web's static works. By default, you should put your js,image,css in the resources/static. If you are using thymeleaf, put the template in the resources. Sample as below.

[image]

This is how you call, note that ../.. actually goes to /resources :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
    href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/signin.css}"
    href="../../css/signin.css" />
</head>
```

UPDATE after OP gave the file structure :
the resources located at webapp/resources which is default static folder for spring mvc ( not spring boot - refer to [this blog](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) ).

The spring boot's static folders are located at (refer to [Spring IO Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) )  :

- /META_INF/resources
- /static
- /resources
- /public

Comment: I edited my question for clarification, I did not use thymleaf for my application and created a webapp folder. The resources folder I referring to is the one under the webapp folder not the resources folder under the `src/main/resources`

Comment: hemm.. that is weird. The default static folders known to Spring boot are /META-INF/resources/, /resources , /static, and /public ... Refer to https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: I found the answer, the webapp/resources is spring mvc default static folder, and not spring boot's. Refer to : http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: @anathema have you resolve your issue? If yes, please accept the answer. :)